# Synapse pipeline failing suddenly - Could not get memory grant

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have a Synapse pipeline that copies data from Data Lakes (CSV) to Azure SQL Pool. It was working fine all of last week.

Suddenly, I'm getting the following error during the copy command in the pipeline:
Could not get the memory grant of 729464 KB because it exceeds the maximum configuration limit in workload group 'SloDWGroupSmall' and resource pool 'SloDWPool'. Contact the server administrator to increase the memory usage limit.

We're using DW300c. This pipeline is copy a bunch of tables that total about 400 million rows.

What could be causing the error? Do I need to scale the SQL Pool? Should I just scale up and scale down during the copy? What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

> What could be causing the error? Do I need to scale the SQL Pool? Should I just scale up and scale down during the copy? What else can I try?

The cause of error can be the at the start of query processing it might be bot getting proper memory required to execution.

To resolve this, you can try with increasing the percentage to allocate the memory by increasing the value of  `REQUEST_MAX_RESOURCE_GRANT_PERCENT`  property of workload group.

```sql
-- Increase the value of GRANT to 50%  
ALTER WORKLOAD GROUP [Group_name] WITH (REQUEST_MAX_RESOURCE_GRANT_PERCENT = 50)  
GO  
-- RECONFIGURE to make the setting take effect  
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Or you can scale up the SQL pool to more `DWUs`

Reference :
[SQL SERVER – How to fix the SQL Server Error 8657 or 8658?](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/02/04/sql-server-how-to-fix-the-sql-server-error-8657-or-8658/)
[Memory and concurrency limits for dedicated SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/memory-concurrency-limits)

Comment: ALTER RESOURCE gives a syntax error in the SQL Pool. Is there another way to make the workload group changes take effect?